# is_dir () function is case sensitive

Tags: php, file, directory

Below is my code

```
<?php
$folder_type=$_POST['folder_type'];
$folder_name=$_POST['folder_name'];
$images="images";
$path="../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name;
if (!is_dir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name)) { 
    mkdir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name); 
    mkdir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name."/".$images); 
    $content = file_get_contents('../../default_code.php');
    $fp = fopen($path . "/$folder_name.php","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp); 
} 
else
{
    echo "0";
}
chmod("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name, 0777);
?>
```

If My Directory is having foldername with name ALTO and If I tried new folder name with alto it won't accept right bt is_dir() function is not checking with casesensitive. If I tried with ALTO it won't accept. So is there any other way to do the checking whether my new foldername already present in directory or not?

Please help anyone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reason for the case sensivity simply is that the file systems typically used on server systems are case sensitive. File systems in unixoid environments have always been case sensitive. It is only MS-Windows that behaves different and on an OSX environment this depends on the configuration.

Comment: Your best approach to your situation simply is to have some discipline and to stick with lower case letters for file names. That way things are unambiguous and thus portable. So you can move your project or application between environments without breaking everything.

Comment: So How can we handle this issue

Comment: @arkascha Really, OSX has a configuration option for this? I never knew.

Comment: strtolower() and I ll try to compare its working now

Comment: @KavyaShree no, `strtolower()` will not solve the issue since it handles only one side.

Comment: Try `file_exists` instead?

Comment: @Xorifelse Yep. Actually the first versions of OSX were using case sensitive file systems. The switch came a few month after the release if I recall correctly. No idea why that was done, though.

Comment: is it possible to check folder availability with file_exists

Comment: Please tell me this is part of some kind of restricted access CMS; dynamically generating directories from a form POST is risky but to then 777 the permissions is just asking for trouble. http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: @arkascha I considered the fs of OSX to be Unix like, guess I was wrong but then again I would be able to install a different fs on Linux as well. You learn the crazy and unexpectedly things here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to avoid any uppercase characters in my folder and file names. I would suggest to always use strtolower() on the folder/file name before applying it. This way also your check would always work out.

```
<?php
$folder_type = strtolower($_POST['folder_type']);
$folder_name = strtolower($_POST['folder_name']);
$images = "images";
$path = "../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name;
if (!is_dir("../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name)) {
    mkdir("../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name);
    mkdir("../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name . "/" . $images);
    $content = file_get_contents('../../default_code.php');
    $fp = fopen($path . "/$folder_name.php", "wb");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    echo "0";
}
chmod("../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name, 0777);
?>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to keep using upper cased names, you could change the if condition to check for both uppercase and lowercase names by first getting a list of all folders and files, looping through them and then check by file name. That would however be inefficient and I see no advantage in trying to keep uppercased names at any cost.

**Edit**

If you don't want to edit any existing folders and files manually into lowercase, you could do the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Check for folder existence by name, case insensitive
 * @param $folder_name
 * @param string $dir
 * @return array
 */
function folder_exists($folder_name, $dir = '*') {
    // get all folders in provided dir
    $folders = array_filter(glob($dir), 'is_dir');

    //now do a case insensitive comparison
    return preg_grep( "/" . $folder_name . "/i" , $folders );
}

$folder_type = strtolower($_POST['folder_type']);
$folder_name = strtolower($_POST['folder_name']);
$images = "images";
$path = "../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name;
if (!folder_exists($folder_type, "../../")){
    mkdir("../../" . $folder_type);
}
if(!folder_exists($folder_name, "../../" . $folder_type)) {
    mkdir($path);
    mkdir($path . "/" . $images);
    $content = file_get_contents('../../default_code.php');
    $fp = fopen($path . "/$folder_name.php", "wb");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    echo "0";
}
chmod("../../" . $folder_type . "/" . $folder_name, 0777);

?>
```

Comment: Only this would not work, if the folder name is "FooBar" !== "foobar" Now if you would get that info from, lets say scandir()..

Comment: It would, if the folder was empty when implemented. FooBar would never get created in the first place~

Comment: I tried this part but when I tried in server it automatically create folder with samename

Comment: Can you be more specific? what did you try, and what was created?

Comment: I tried to create folder with name figo but the directory already having foldername with FIGO if it so it wont create new folder

Comment: That's the point @Xorifelse tried to make. There are two ways to handle this, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtolower`,so it create lowercase folder and you have no worries in dir checking

```
$folder_type=$_POST['folder_type'];
$folder_name=$_POST['folder_name'];

$folder_type = strtolower( $folder_type );
$folder_name = strtolower( $folder_name );  

$images="images";

$path="../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name;
if (!is_dir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name)) 
{ 
    mkdir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name); 
    mkdir("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name."/".$images); 
    $content = file_get_contents('../../default_code.php');
    $fp = fopen($path . "/$folder_name.php","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp); 
} 
else
{
    echo "0";
}
chmod("../../".$folder_type."/".$folder_name, 0777);
```

Comment: Only this would not work, if the folder name is `"FooBar" !== "foobar"` Now if you would get that info from, lets say `scandir()`..

Comment: Yea.But it will not create duplicate directory in future

Comment: I tried this part but when I tried in server it automatically create folder with samename